# Using macros with the same name in different header files

Tags: c

I use macros like #DEBUG to print some additional debugging info and even possibly do something differently to help me with debugging. For example:

in header a.h:

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

in src a.c:

```
#include "a.h"

int func_a () {
/*some code*/
#if DEBUG
//do this
#endif
}
```

What will happen if I use a macro with the same name in another file ?

header b.h

```
#define DEBUG 1
#if DEBUG
    # define PRINT 1
#elif
    #define PRINT 0
#endif
```

src b.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int func_b () {
/*some code*/
#if PRINT
//do this
#endif
/*some code*/
#if DEBUG
//do this
#endif
}
```

What will happen if I change the value of #DEBUG in one of the headers? I saw in some other answers that redefining a macro is not allowed in the C standard. But when I compile with GCC using the -Wall flag I see no errors or warnings.

Comment: If you define a macro more than once in a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) you should get an error or warning. Which version of GCC do you use? How did you build your program? Is the code you show an actual [mcve] which can be used to replicate the lack of warning?

Comment: Seems like gcc doesn't error if the definitions are the same. [C11 6.10.3p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3p2) bop

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Redefining the macro with the same definition (as in this case) is allowed.

Comment: worth mentioning, to check *whether or not a macro is defined* you should probably be using `ifdef` and `ifndef` or `if defined(MACRONAME)`

Comment: interjay has the correct answer to the question - redefining with same definition should be fine but redefining same macro with a different definition is not allowed and should error out

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using gcc 10.0.1 (Experimental) but I also just now tried with gcc 7.5.0. No warnings or erros. I updated the code for what I think might be a clearer example.

Comment: @interjay So if DEBUG were to be defined differently, e.g. 0, in one of the headers I would get an error ? If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You will get warning for macro redefinition and the last definition will be used.

Comment: @acevans, GCC is non-conforming by default.  Compile with the `-pedantic` option to get all (or at least most) of the required diagnostics that it omits by default.  Also turn on `-std=c11` to get strict(ish) conformance to C11 if that matters to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen if I use a macro with the same name in another file ?

It depends.  C does not allow an identifier that is already defined as a macro name at some point in a translation unit to be defined again at that point, unless the redefinition specifies an identical replacement list.  This is a language constraint, so conforming implementations will emit a diagnostic about violations they perceive.  Compilers may reject code that contains violations, and if they nevertheless accept such code then the resulting behavior is undefined as far as C is concerned.

In practice, implementations that do accept such violations have two reasonable choices (and a universe of unreasonable ones):

- ignore the redefinition, or
- process the redefinition as if it were proceeded by an `#undefine` directive specifying the affected macro name.

Implementations of which I am aware accept such redefinitions and implement the latter option, at least by default.

If your headers are defining macros solely for their own internal use then you may be able to address the issue by exercising some discipline:

1. Each header puts all its `#include` directives at the beginning, before any definition of the possibly-conflicting macro(s).
2. Each header `#undefine`s the possibly-conflicting macro at the end, under all conditional-compilation scenarios in which the macro may be defined in the first place.

On the other hand, if the macro is intended to be referenced by files that use the header(s) where it is defined then undefining it within the header would defeat the purpose.  Under some circumstances, probably including yours, you can address that by defining the macro only conditionally in each header:

```
#if !defined(DEBUG)
#define DEBUG 1
#endif
```

That will avoid redefinition, instead using (only) the first definition encountered, which may even come from compiler command-line arguments.  If you do this, however, it is essential that all the default definitions specified in that way be the same, else changing your headers' inclusion order will have unexpected effects code that depends on which definition is used.